# How should I add Korean Keyboard on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, ibus

I am wondering how to add a Korean Keyboard for my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I already tried to install iBus, then after having installed Korean language, I chose "ibus" for my Keyboard input method system in the same "Language Support" window. However, this did not work.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBus is no longer the default IM framework in Ubuntu for typing Korean; Fcitx is. Hence the `fcitx-hangul` package was installed when you installed the Korean language, not `ibus-hangul`.

Either you can switch to *fcitx* in Language Support, or if you want to use IBus you can install `ibus-hangul` manually.

Then next time you log in you should find Hangul in *Text Entry*.

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html#complex